# jquery animate dont fire unless value is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a grid width dynamic boxes where on parent mouseleave if input value is changed the boxes resize. Equal resize is not complete but for the purpose of this question it works.

in boxes add anything that equals to 100 eg: 40 10 10 10 30  or  50 50 0 0 0
http://jsfiddle.net/MT4Fp/16/

```
$('ul').on('mouseleave', function (event) {

    var elems = $(this).find('input');
    elems.each(function (el, i) {

        $(this).parent().parent().animate({
            width: $(this).val() + '%'
        }, 500);

        if ($(this).val() <= 1) {
            $(this).parent().parent().addClass('hidden');
        } else if ($(this).val() > 1) {
            $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('hidden');
        }

    });


});
```

problem i have is that on mouseleave even if you dont change anything the animate starts animating , you can see this when you enter/leave the grid , the size of grid will change for few sec. 
how can i run animate only if the input is changed? I have tried , keyup , change and few other methods but could not get it to work. The main thing is that the animation fires only on grid leave and if something is changed.

any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: can't you cache the value of input in a var, and put the animation in a if ... check?

Comment: I tried that also , added the values inside an array but did not work, does the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, a comment is not to big.

```
var i = $("#inputid").val();
$('ul').on('mouseleave', function (event) {
    if ($("#inputid").val() == i){return true;}
    EDITED: i = $("#inputid").val();
    var elems = $(this).find('input');
    elems.each(function (el, i) {
        $(this).parent().parent().animate({
            width: $(this).val() + '%'}, 500);
            if ($(this).val() <= 1) {
                $(this).parent().parent().addClass('hidden');
            } else if ($(this).val() > 1) {
                $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('hidden');
            }
    });
});
```

Also, you may consider targeting elements like $('ul').on('mouseleave','.i',....)
Sorry, I edited. If it is a change, addit to the value of i var.

Comment: almost , it catches the animation on the second pass again. you change once, in/out and is there again, but i see what you are getting at

Comment: I choose yours since it got me to the right track , what I did is on enter record values and on leave match them with recorded ones , if they differ than animate and record new values

Answer (score 0):

You want to animate for value change, not for 'mouseleave'. So bind value change with this method.

```
jQuery('input[type="text"]').on('input', function() {
    // do work such as  animate ...
    console.log($(this).val()); // i tried with this and get value
})
```

Comment: no actually I must animate on parent mouselevae , otherwise it will change widths while you are entering the values

Comment: "how can i run animate only if the input is changed? " was your question. So you should bind with value change event, not with mouseleave ..isn't that(?)

Comment: please dont just read the title of the question but the explanation as well. I add the code samples so it should not be that hard to understand what I need